# Pagination with ngHandsontable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, handsontable

I'm new to Angular and trying out the Angular wrapper for a new project I'm working on which is based on Angular technologies. Previously it was very easy to use pagination use # links as per the demo on the main site:

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/demo-pagination.html

What would be the most practical way to replicate this behaviour with ngHandsontable?

I know that Angular routing uses the # tags, but this can be disabled using html5 mode.

Answer (score 0):

A new sample has been posted on their website showing how to use pagination.

http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/demo/#/pagination-columns-pagination